# Azure CLI in a Docker Container

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, pip, dockerfile

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image that I need Azure CLI installed in. For a Docker image, it seems the preferred way is to use `pip`, however, I have other pip Azure libraries needed in the container that overlap with the CLI install and get blown away because Azure CLI requires older versions; then making it so I can't run my python scripts.

I have tried to use the [script installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?view=azure-cli-latest) but that hasn't worked and errored out because I believe the install is interactive.

The last option I can find is the [manual apt install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest), though I am not sure this is a correct way nor do I have a good idea of how to replicate that in a `Dockerfile`.

Is there a preferred/good way of getting Azure CLI in a container not using `pip`?

```
    FROM ubuntu:18.04

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
        apt-get -f -y install curl python3-pip python-pip && \
        pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
        pip2 install --upgrade pip && \
        pip3 install azure-storage-blob==12.3.0 & \\
        pip3 install azure-cli
```

Comment: Can you share your current Dockerimage (at least the `FROM` and the `RUN` command(s) that run `apt-get`?

Comment: @jmaitrehenry Sure. I updated it with the from and run of my Dockerfile. The reason I'm using pip2 and pip3 to install stuff is because I am having the same problem with packages stepping over each other for ansible and the storage-blob library. Now adding the Azure cli, I  am unable to get around it with attaching it to pip2 or 3 like I did with the Ansible azure package. That is why I am trying to find an alternative to installing Azure cli, to avoid it interfering with pip packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a preference to use the package manager to install dependencies, it's why I will do something like that:

- Add base dependencies for https repostory and curl
- Add the gpg key and repository for the CLI
- Add the CLI

This is the Dockerfile with thoses steps:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -f -y install curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg python3-pip python-pip && \
    curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg && \
    CLI_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) && \
    echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ ${CLI_REPO} main" \
    > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y azure-cli && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

In addition, I clean up the apt cache by removing `/var/lib/apt/lists`. Tt reduces the image size, since the apt cache is not stored in a layer.

Comment: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade &&     apt-get -f -y install curl apt-transport-https lsb-release gnupg python3-pip python-pip &&     curl -sL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc.gpg &&     CLI_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs) &&     echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ ${CLI_REPO} main"     > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y azure-cli &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100

Answer (score 1):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt#option-1-install-with-one-command

```
RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Can you help me with the alternate command for Alpine as the base image?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to install azure cli in alpine linux see: [Install Azure CLI in Alpine Docker Container](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/19591)

If required, make sure that your python environment is activated and necessary permissions are given to activate the environment.

DockerFile with `alpine` as base image:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add py3-pip
RUN apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo make
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install azure-cli
CMD sh
```